# Activemq is not running even if nothing is running on port 61616

Tags: activemq-classic

Hi I'm using activemq for our project and every time I run activemq in our local network but I'm always getting this error even though nothing is running on port 61616

> 2013-04-03 08:48:28,139 | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ
> (localhost, ID:batag-1562-1364950107650-0:1). Reason:
> java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in
> JMX: Failed to bind to server socket:
> tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600
> due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind |
> org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main java.io.IOException:
> Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to
> server socket:
> tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600
> due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

I tested on other routers, sometimes it does work but most of the time I get this error.

Comment: clearly something is running on 61616, probably activemq, although you think not.

Check with netstat -aot | find "LISTENING" (Windows - similar commands exists for other OS). Then you can figure out which process is using this port

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, nothing was showing up with netstat.

Solution was to disable "Internet Connection Sharing" service.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Control Panel -- > View Network Connections --> Right click on your connected network and click on properties.

A new pop up window appears. in that window select sharing tab and disable network sharing.

Automatically 61616 port will released. and you can start activemq